# Export everything in Typescript Module Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I just want to export everything inside a Typescript Module, say for example I declare a module like this:

```
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/express/express.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts' />

import express = require("express");
import mongoose = require("mongoose");

export module Users {

    export var users: Express = express();
    export var base_URL: string = "/users";

    users.get(base_URL, (req, res) => {
        res.render("index", {
            title: "Cheese cakes"
        });
    });
}
```

Now, as you can see in order to get access to `base_URL` and `users`, I need to export them explicitly as well. What can I do to say, that I want to export everything inside a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items inside a module are private by default unless you `explicitly` export them.

PS: there is little advantage of declaring an internal module when using nodeJS with TypeScript. Each file in nodeJS is a module and only things you `explicitly` export are available at the import location. So I would write:

```
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/express/express.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts' />

import express = require("express");
import mongoose = require("mongoose");

export var users: Express = express();
export var base_URL: string = "/users";

users.get(base_URL, (req, res) => {
    res.render("index", {
        title: "Cheese cakes"
    });
});
```